# Set Image on ImageView from pc to Android

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm working in an application that shows some user data and I want to show the image of the user,the problem is that the images are stored in a folder on my computer and in the MySQL database I only store de path of each image.

How can I send the image files via PHP/XML and catch them in Android?

I was thinking in store the paths in an array like this:

```
<?php
require_once('databaseconnection.php');

$img=array();

$sql=mysqli_query($CON,"SELECT RutaImagen FROM terminales");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $img[]="".getcwd()."\\imgterminales".$row['RutaImagen']."";
}

print_r($img);

mysqli_close($CON);
?>
```

This works well and this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/kaba.jpg
    [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/pelonchas.png
    [2] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/finanzas1.jpg
    [3] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/finanzas2.jpg
    [4] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/vader.jpg
    [5] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/gandalf.jpg
    [6] => C:\xampp\htdocs\fisgon\imgterminales/default.jpg
)
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. The `android-studio` was completely irrelevant to what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it is hosting them in the web..